# entity framework 6 can't insert record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

if I define a sequence and a table like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[seq-test] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 0
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTab] 
(
    [iden] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [seq-test]),
    [name1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [name2] [nchar](10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [iden] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then try to insert data using EF 6:

```
testTab d = new testTab();
d.name1 = "sss";

using (var db = new ABEntities2())
{
    db.testTabs.Add(d);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and I set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity` for `iden` column, it doesn't behave as it should, Exception thrown by `SaveChanges` is `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`:

*Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.*

what am I doing wrong?

generated testTabs:

```
<EntitySetMapping Name="testTabs">
  <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="ABModel.testTab">
    <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="testTab">
      <ScalarProperty Name="iden" ColumnName="iden" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="name1" ColumnName="name1" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="name2" ColumnName="name2" />
    </MappingFragment>
  </EntityTypeMapping>
</EntitySetMapping>
```

Comment: can you include your testTabs class?

Comment: I think, you have included an unwanted Parenthesis, while creating. (
    [iden] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]. There was a double closing. But A single opening

Comment: one couple of parentheses is for primary key definition, the other for create table - I modified indentation only for better readability

Answer (score 0):

I would check these things

1. Make sure the `[Key]` on the `testTabs` class is being set
2. Make sure you don't have two different instances of `ABEntities2 (DbContext)` at the same time

Comment: it was set automatically: `<Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="iden" />
          </Key>`

Answer (score 0):

looks like the only problem is usage of `sequence`, since I changed table definition to

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTab]
(
    [iden] [bigint] identity(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    [name1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [name2] [nchar](10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [iden] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

- so I used `identity` instead of `sequence` and recreated model, everything works fine. `sequence` introduced in sql2012 seems not working with EF6 correctly.